# Selecting nodes based on the value of an attribute of a sibbling node selected by a child of the sibbiling

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Relatively new to XSLT.  I've taken a class and seem to be getting the hang of it but this one has stumped me.

My organization has a third party system that generates XML outputs at various times.  We have a utility that applies XSLT ans passes it on to the other organizations that require the information. The generated XML has a section structured like the one below with related data contained in NodeType1 and NodeType2 nodes.

The new information that we have to send first targets NodeType1 nodes where the TargetElement's value is true. We then need to select NodeType2 nodes where their ConID attribute value is the same as the ConID attribute's values for those NodeType1 nodes that were selected.  In the provided example, those NodeType2 nodes who's ConID attribute values are 123456 and 964589 should be selected.

So I've tried several combinations of conditionals with no luck.  The last one I tried looks like

```
<xsl:apply-template select="NodeType2[./NodeType2/Container/Connection/@ConID = ../NodeType1/Container/Connection[TargetNode = 'True']/Connection/@ConID]
```

I've gone through so many at this point I can't say for certain what else I've tried

Any assistance would be much appreciated at this point.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<Section>
    <NodeType1>
        <Container>
            <TargetElement>True</TargetElement>
            <Connection ConID="123456"></Connection>
        </Container>
      </NodeType1>
      <NodeType1>
        <Container>
            <Connection ConID="999999"></Connection>
        </Container>
      </NodeType1>
      <NodeType1>
        <Container>
        <TargetElement>True</TargetElement>
        <Connection ConID="964589"></Connection>
    </Container>
  </NodeType1>
  <NodeType2>
    <Container>
        <NameInformation>
            <First>Jo</First>
            <Last>Shmo</Last>
        </NameInformation>
        <Connection ConID="123456"></Connection>
    </Container>
  </NodeType2>
  <NodeType2>
    <Container>
        <NameInformation>
            <First>Who</First>
            <Last>First</Last>
        </NameInformation>
        <Connection ConID="999999"></Connection>
    </Container>
  </NodeType2>
  <NodeType2>
    <Container>
        <NameInformation>
            <First>What</First>
            <Last>Second</Last>
        </NameInformation>
        <Connection ConID="964589"></Connection>
    </Container>
  </NodeType2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a cross-reference - and XSLT has a special feature to resolve cross-references named [**keys**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key).

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="type2" match="NodeType2/Container" use="Connection/@ConID" />

<xsl:template match="/Section">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="NodeType1/Container[TargetElement='True']">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('type2', Connection/@ConID)/NameInformation"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <NameInformation>
    <First>Jo</First>
    <Last>Shmo</Last>
  </NameInformation>
  <NameInformation>
    <First>What</First>
    <Last>Second</Last>
  </NameInformation>
</output>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  I'm getting some extra XML but I'm guessing that it is because the actual structure is more complex than the example.  I'm getting data at this point so I'm sure that I can eliminate the extra.

And working this out on my own will help me understand this concept better, so bonus for me.  =)